# Renaming multi index in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, indexing

Is there a way to rename an index in a multi-index data frame?

Example

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame([
['green','M', 10.1, 'class2'],
['red', 'L', 13.5, 'class1']])
df.columns = ['color', 'size', 'price', 'classifier']

df.set_index(['color','size'], inplace=True)
```

Gives

```
            price   classifier
color   size

green   M   10.1    class2
red     L   13.5    class1
```

I want to rename the index 'size' to become size_modified

```
df.rename(index={'size': 'Size_Mod'}, inplace=True)
```

didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need [`df.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html) instead of `df.rename`:

```
df = df.rename_axis(index={'size': 'Size_Mod'})
```

---

```
print(df)

                price classifier
color Size_Mod                  
green M          10.1     class2
red   L          13.5     class1
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, make sure the order of the names is correct. But it has a smaller fingerprint!

```
df.index.names = ['color','Size_Mod']
```